# Different ways to save form values to the database

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

I have started learning Django recently using a Udemy course. While going through the course instructor asked to save values from a Form to database. 
After searching on the internet I figured out how to put form values into database and everything is working fine. Below is my `views.py` and `forms.py` files.

**forms.py**

```
class FormName(forms.Form):
fname = forms.CharField( label="First Name")
lname = forms.CharField(label="Last name:")
email = forms.EmailField()
verify_email = forms.EmailField(label='Verify Email:')

def clean(self):
    all_clean_data = super().clean()
    email = all_clean_data['email']
    vmail = all_clean_data['verify_email']

    if email != vmail:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Check the emails")
```

**views.py**

```
def signup(request):
form = forms.FormName()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = forms.FormName(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        post = User()
        post.fname=request.POST.get('fname')
        post.lname=request.POST.get('lname')
        post.email=request.POST.get('email')
        post.save()
        return render(request,'third_app/greet.html')
    else:
        return render(request,'third_app/oops.html',{'form':form})

return render(request, 'third_app/signup.html',{'form':form})
```

Now coming to question, the instructor is using `Meta` class to store the form values to the database. Below are his `forms.py` and `views.py` files. I am curious about what the difference is between my method and the instructor's.

**forms.py**

```
class FormName(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta():
          model = User    
          fields = 'all'
```

**views.py**

```
def signup(request):
form = forms.FormName()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = forms.FormName(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save(commit=True)
        return render(request,'third_app/greet.html')
    else:
        return render(request,'third_app/oops.html',{'form':form})

return render(request, 'third_app/signup.html',{'form':form})
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/) explain this very well. It's what is known as a `ModelForm`:

> If you’re building a database-driven app, chances are you’ll have forms that map closely to Django models. For instance, you might have a BlogComment model, and you want to create a form that lets people submit comments. In this case, it would be redundant to define the field types in your form, because you’ve already defined the fields in your model.
>   For this reason, Django provides a helper class that lets you create a Form class from a Django model.

So, to answer your question, your method uses a regular form (`forms.Form`) where you define the form fields, perform validation and then save each field individually in your view. When using `form.ModelForm`, field validation and saving is taken care of for you. Seeing as you have already defined what your fields are, the `ModelForm` uses this to perform the validation. The `save()` method conveniently saves each field to the database.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the difference.
Now I see, I have used a regular `forms.Form` in which I have to manually define fields and can decide which value to ask from user and later on which values to put into the database. 
I know about the exclude and include attributes of `ModelForm`, so a follow up question is can I add extra fields for verification(e.g. To verify email) in ModelForm or will I have to resort to `forms.Form`?

Comment: Yes, you can include other fields which are not part of your model.

Comment: @RishabKaushik please consider marking this answer as accepted if it answered your question.